# Error de sintaxis al ejecutar query en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Quiero copiar procedimientos almacenados y funciones de una base de datos a otra, al exportar una función en mysql, cuando exporto una función este me genera un query que tengo que pegar en la bd donde quiero la función. Pero al ejecutarlo me sale el error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near**

Este es el query:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER = `ipnmedup_admin` @`209.45.111.194` FUNCTION `fun_PromedioNota`(`in_alumno` varchar(40),
`in_Especialidad` varchar(20)) RETURNS text CHARSET latin1
BEGIN

RETURN (
select
    concat(sum(Data.NotaFinal * Data.Creditos )/ sum(Data.Creditos), '||', sum(Data.Creditos), '||', sum(Data.NotaFinal * Data.Creditos ) ) Puntaje
from
    (
    select
        dn.CURSOS,
        dn.CICLOS,
        case
            when max(FINAL)>10 then max(FINAL)
            else 0
        end NotaFinal,
        case
            when max(FINAL)>10 then max(dn.CREDIT_COMPLEM)
            else max(dn.CREDIT_COMPLEM)
        end Creditos
    from
        data_Notas dn
    left join data_Cursos cur
on
        dn.CURSOS = cur.CURSOS
    where
        dn.CODIPN = in_Alumno
        and dn.ESPECI = in_Especialidad
        and cur.DESCUR like 'Practica D%'
    group by
        dn.CURSOS
)


 Data);
END
```

Comment: ¿ _Near_ dónde? ¡Esa es la parte fundamental del error!

Comment: Tan solo añade un [*delimitador*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html).